# What should I do when a plugin is not updated anymore?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

The author of a plugin has abandoned it. The community has created patches and I have created updates. Right now it's in another public repository but it's becoming unyielding to maintain both. Is it possible to fork it?

**UPDATE**
The link in the similar post provided some answers. But it did not answer can I create my own version?

Comment: From that answer it sounds like I need to talk to plugins @ wordpress and the plugin author. Let me add, can I create my own version?

Comment: That depends on the licence that the plugin has been published under.